# Format SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField

Tags: 2013, page-layout, date-time

I am using this to return the date/time entered by a user in a page layout.  I want to only show the date.  I need to keep the time part as this is used in a query on another page.  I have seen suggestions in adding Dateonly:"True" but this doesn't work.  Can I use CSS or something else to format / hide the time

```
<span id="publishdate">
        <br><i>Article Date:</i></br>   <SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField  FieldName="ea266b0f-51ec-4fd3-bdcf-0c010a4caea7" runat="server" ></SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField>
        </span>
```

Comment: Have you tried editing the field property and setting it to only date?

Comment: I can't edit it to date only  as I use the time part to sort by.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but this might help. [Change dates view.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshuag/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl/)